# Do any stores play "Mosquito" noises that annoy teenagers but cannot be heard by adults?

Tags: physiology

I've heard (no pun intended) some claims that some storefronts in shopping malls play a noise that sounds like a mosquito, which apparently can't be heard by adults yet drives teenagers nuts.  The purpose of this noise is to keep teenagers from loitering at the storefront's entrance.

I've heard a few of these noises on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mosquito+noise&aq=0&oq=mosquito+no).  However, every single one of these sound clips are perfectly audible to me.  Better still, they don't really bother me at all.

I guess I'm skeptical because the majority of these stores have employees who would be painfully affected by his noise.

So is it true that stores have used such a noise and is it effective?

Comment: I know many stores that play sounds that are annoying to adults, but don't bother teenagers...

Comment: Adults can't hear mosquitos?

Comment: @Zano: i don't know the frequency of a real mosquitos sound, but the ability to hear high frequencys gets lost when you get old ([known as Presbycusis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presbycusis)). so when you play a sound at 17.5 kHz, most people older than ~25 years won't hear it while most people below that age will.

Comment: There is a shopping mall in Southampton, UK that plays this noise at its entrance. Unfortunately, it is also right next to a major bus stop and is incredibly annoying if you have to wait longer than a few minutes for a bus.

Comment: @Zano - I cant.  I remember the sound from when i was a kid but No.  Here is a [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_GrIzcxClM) clip of the sound that only the one intern(only one under 30 in my group) could hear.

Comment: A specific example of a store doing this is Supermacs in Eyre Square, Galway, Ireland. I can't give this an answer as I can't find a source stating it except people in forums and on blogs. It was installed as many young people tend to gather outside after nightclubs close. Installing it changed nothing, so I wouldn't consider it terribly effective.

Answer (score 13):

There is a [product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mosquito) developed for that purpose. It was installed in at least one shop in South Wales where [it was banned by community officials for violation human rights](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/wales/4839346.stm).

In France, a local court [banned the device](http://www.lefigaro.fr/actualites/2008/04/30/01001-20080430ARTFIG00369-la-justice-interdit-le-boitier-anti-jeunes.php), but there don't seem to be any nationwide bans of the device, at least not in Europe. According to civil rights groups, such a device probably [violates the European Convention on Human Rights](http://www.heise.de/tp/artikel/24/24893/1.html) or national laws, [like the Non-fatal Offences against the Person Act in Ireland](http://www.irishexaminer.com/archives/2007/0530/ireland/using-mosquito-devices-on-children-could-constitute-assault-says-ombudsman-33884.html).

Comment: This answer does not really address the second part of the question on weather these devices are effective.

Comment: Has there been any reports of its effectiveness?